# MIMEType association incorrect for FireFox?

Tags: firefox, npapi, browser-plugin

I'm working with an existing ActiveX control, we have a NPAPI for it, and it works well for the most part in FireFox.

It supports viewing image types, one type, TIFF works well but for some reason JPG doesn't.

So I simplified MIMEType in my .rc file to be simply "image/tiff".  That works well, I can drag a *.tif file into FireFox and the plugin loads.

However when I my MIMEType is defined as simply "image/jpeg", it doesn't work for *.jpg files and FF just natively displays the JPG instead of letting my plugin do it.  I tried "image/jpe" and that works for *.jpe files.  I also tried "image/jpg", but no luck.  Is JPG a special case for NPAPI?

Additionally, I can get my plugin to load for *.jp2 files when I specify "image/jp2".  I don't seem to have any other plugin installed that would be loading the JPG instead.  In fact, plugin-container.exe doesn't even load when FireFox displays the JPG so that makes me think it has something to do with FF's native display overriding my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For supported (built-in) image types, plugins are not considered (i don't think any browser does that).
TIFF is not a supported image type for Firefox, hence plugins are used if they handle that mimetype/extension.

*Note*: When handling image mimetypes you are prone to colliding with other plugins (Quicktime specifically) - there are no real guarantees on which plugin will be used if more than one supports a specific mimetype or extension.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't surprise me at all if Firefox is overriding your plugin; the last thing they want is for a plugin to be able to take over viewing basic filetypes.  I'm kinda surprised overriding tiff worked, to be honest.